# How to have a "saved search" in Twitter only return english results?

Tags: twitter

Twitter supports saving a specific search.  However, it just seems to be the basic string search as opposed their advanced search on search.twitter.com.  The advanced search allows you to select a language you would like the results in.  How do I get the advanced search to be saved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply add `lang:en` to the search query. e.g.

```
cats lang:en
```

Comment: The OP's question is about Twitter. Does this apply to a Twitter search as well?

Comment: Absolutely! stackexchange is just an example search *on* Twitter.

Comment: I can confirm that if you set up a search like this on the website, it works perfectly on phone clients like tweetbot

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following operators in a saved search;

https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tags/twitter/info

But language doesn't appear to be among them, it also appears not to be listed in the 'New Twitter' advanced search page;

https://twitter.com/#!/search-advanced

Answer (score 1):

Bookmark the avanced search page in your browser. Press Ctrl+D for bookmark.

So that you can directly use this bookmark for search results.

Comment: Good suggestion and very clear.  Since the built-in searches are saved in Twitter, they show up in my twitter clients in my phone.  But maybe I should just use the browser in my phone for this function.  Thanks.